# How to pre-populate the sms body text via an html link without filling the phone no. in iphone

Tags: jquery, html, text, hyperlink, sms

I tried all the ways possible to pre populate the sms via link without displaying any phone no. on Iphone but it didnt work out and the To section is being filled by ; or & or ? whatever I am giving in the link .
Attaching the screenshot of the error. And also the line being used for it.

```
<a href="sms:?&body=look>sms</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out there are hacks or ways around this. The below code should work for both Android and IOS.

```
// Without Contact Number
<a href="sms:?&body=message">Text Message</a>

// With Contact Number
<a href="sms:1234567890;?&body=message">Text Message</a>
```

Give it a try and let me know.